# Parse out certain tags in Batch script

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am needing help with writing a script, but unsure of the logic to use.

Here is a sample of what I am dealing with.

```
<Section name="Server_Default-Exclusions">
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_0" value="4|3|Thing1"/>
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_1" value="4|3|Thing2"/>
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_2" value="4|3|Thing3"/>

<Section name="Wrkstn_Default-Exclusions">
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_0" value="4|3|Thing1"/>
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_1" value="4|3|Thing2"/>
<Setting name="ExcludedItem_2" value="4|3|Thing3"/>
```

I need the sections for Server's to go into one file and Workstations to go in another.  The XML I am looking at has over 200k lines in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to get the values or you want to edit the xml?

Comment: Microsoft has created three other scripting languages that have methods to parse XML correctly. Jscript, Vbscript and Powershell.

Comment: Have the file _several_ separated Server and Workstation sections? Or just one of each like in the example...

Comment: I am wanting to have all workstation sections go into "Workstations.txt", then all server sections go into "Server.txt".  The original XML does not need to be modified.  I will have to look into those other scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with [**`xpath.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath0.1.bat) :

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::change the value here with the relative or full path to the xml file
set "xml_file=E:\scripts\xml_Test.xml"
set counter=0

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath0.1.bat xml_Test.xml "//Section/Setting/@value"') do (
    set "values[!counter!]=%%#"
    set /a counter=counter+1
)

::list values
set values[
```